# Como validar que no se pueda cambiar el estado de un producto si se encuentra registrado en uno o más pedidos

Tags: sql-server

Buen día a todos espero me puedan ayudar con esta duda de antemano gracias.

Tengo una tabla de productos con los siguientes campos

```
Id_Producto, 
Descripcion, 
Id_Categoria,
Id_Color, 
Activo,
```

El campo Activo es de tipo bit y me sirve para cambiar el estado del producto; es decir, si el usuario selecciona un producto y hace clic en eliminar, este solo cambia de estado de `1` a `0`; lo que seria un borrado lógico, recibiendo como parámetro el `id` del producto.

Por otra parte tengo dos tablas que son

```
pedidos 
detallepedido
```

En mi tabla `detallepedido` se registran los productos que el cliente solicita, ademas de que esta tabla tiene un campo llamado `estatus` el cual puede tener dos valores que son `activo` y `surtido`. Un pedido puede tener muchos productos y por cada pedido un estatus.

Mi problema es cuando quiero dar de baja un producto, no puedo hacerlo si este se encuentra `activo` en uno o varios pedidos. Lo que quiero que haga esta consulta es lo siguiente:

Supongamos que  tengo tres pedidos con el mismo producto y diferente estatus, en los dos primeros seria activo y en el tercero surtido; por lo que si yo quiero dar de baja este producto debería de comparar el estatus de los tres pedidos y si es surtido para los tres me permite dar de baja el producto pero, si en alguno aún esta activo, no me permita dar de baja ese producto.  Hasta hora lo que hace mi consulta es dar de baja el producto.

Cuando su estado es el mismo para cada pedido, pero si tengo en un pedido activo y en otro surtido me lo da de baja y no debería por que aun hay un pedido activo con ese producto

la consulta que implemente:

```
UPDATE Producto SET Activo = 0 
FROM Producto p
INNER JOIN PtPhylon.dbo.Dpedido on p.Id_Producto = d.Id_Producto
WHERE d.Estatus = '30' and p.Id_Producto = ?
```

Comment: Antes que nada, necesitas validar que ese producto no exista en la tabla Dpedido, con estatus activo, antes de hacer ese update, ya que ese update le cambia el estatus al producto cuando encuentre 1 pedido con estatus surtido, pero sin importarle si hay otros 10 con estatus activo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo la línea que ya traes, que entiendo que es que el `update` simplemente no haga nada si el artículo tiene pedidos activos, entonces, te funcionaría valiéndote de la clausula `not exists`. Algo como:

```
update Producto 
   set Activo = 0 
 where Id_Producto = ?
   and not exists (select 1
                     from PtPhylon.dbo.Dpedido d
                    where d.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto
                      and d.estatus = 'activo');
```

Sin embargo, te recomiendo re-pensar este enfoque. Suponiendo que esto sea parte de una aplicación, esto simplemente *no haría nada* de manera silenciosa. Considero que es mejor hacer una validación explícita e informar al usuario, generando un error. Conlleva un poco más de esfuerzo pero manteniendo este enfoque, en una aplicación con cientos o miles de *acciones* de esta naturaleza, el funcionamiento de la aplicación se hace más fácil de entender para el usuario y más fácil de depurar para el programador.

En SQL Server, podrías elevar un error valiéndote de [`raiserror`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), quedando algo como esto:

```
if not exists (select 1
             from PtPhylon.dbo.Dpedido d 
            where d.Id_Producto = ?
              and d.estatus = 'activo')
 update Producto
    set Activo = 0
  where Id_Producto = ?
else
  raiserror ('No puede inactivarse el producto debido a que tiene pedidos activos', 16, 1);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte fue de gran ayuda.

Comment: Un placer, me alegra ser de ayuda :)